# Regular expression for two following proper nouns

Tags: regex, nlp

I am trying to build a script that should give you a list of the proper names of a text. I want to build a regular expression that matchs every word that starts with a capital letter and that doesn't start a stence. An example from the text:

> "But while he thought about these things, behold, an angel of the Lord
>   appeared to him in a dream, saying: Joseph, son of David, do not be
>   afraid to take to you Mary your wife, for that which is conceived in
>   her is of the Holy Spirit. She is going to have a son. You must give him the name Jesus. That’s because he will save his people from their sins.

I want that the regexp matches: "Lord", "Joseph", "David", "Mary", "Holy" and "Spirit". It should not match "But", "She", "You" or "That". So I did this:

```
[a-z,;:] +([A-Z][a-z]+)[\W]
```

This matchs Lord, Joseph, David, Mary and Holy, BUT not Spirit. And that is my problem: after finding "Holy", the regexp keeps going searching in the text the pattern; to find "Spirit", the regexp should take the "y" of "Holy" in consideration for the first square bracket. So, after finding "Holy" should restart not after "Holy". I have tried it also with non matching groups, like:

```
(?:[a-z,;:]) +([A-Z][a-z]+)[\W]
```

But that is also not the answer. I would be very thankful if anyone would help.
Regards!

Comment: This would be much easier IMO if you split the string into sentences, and then extract out the proper nouns one at a time.  What language are you using?

Comment: Spanish! You mean to split first the text into string that start with a capital letter and ends with a .?!

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for the help. The script that I did is now in github: https://github.com/cligs/toolbox/blob/master/assist_metadata.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex

```
(?<=[a-z,;:] )([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK8fO2/7)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [65-69] `Lord`
MATCH 2
1.  [106-112]   `Joseph`
MATCH 3
1.  [121-126]   `David`
MATCH 4
1.  [160-164]   `Mary`
MATCH 5
1.  [221-225]   `Holy`
MATCH 6
1.  [226-232]   `Spirit`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that works better! But I would prefer a way that separetes "Holy" and "Spirit" in different matchs. So the matches would be: "Lord", "Joseph", "David", "Mary", "Holy", "Spirit". Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @José split match on space

Comment: Thank you, that is correct. And the other answer is also right :) many thanks!

Comment: After trying it a little bit, I liked it better that the white space in the first bracket. By the way, for Spanish it would be:

(?<=[a-z,;:] )([A-ZÁ-ÚÜÑ][a-zá-úñü]+)

Comment: @Jose But it would fail this case `You owe me 4$ Obama`

Comment: Then add `$` into `(?<=[a-z,;:\$] )([A-Z][a-z]+)` anyway Bible has no $ : )

Comment: @Tim007 haha my point was, it is better to use negative lookbehind isntead of lookahead for such cases (then you would have to add all othere currencies as well ). (never realised it was bible :P)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
(?<![.!?;]) ([A-Z]\w+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU9gT0/1)

Comment: Right, this regexp will also match the words at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: The answer from @timo007 is algo :P